# High Lighthouse Total Blocking Time despite no long task

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse, web-performance

[According to Google document](https://web.dev/articles/tbt#how_does_tbt_relate_to_tti) the main criteria for the Google Chrome Lighthouse tool to calculate the Total Blocking Time (TBT) is [long task](https://w3c.github.io/longtasks/).

From my understanding, a Long task is any JavaScript that executes longer than 50 ms anything longer than that will add up to the TBT.

After I finish profiling my web application there is 1 long task 90 ms long.
Which means I should have 40 ms of TBT.

But after I ran the lighthouse 3 times I got around 1300 ms of TBT on average

How is TBT is actually calculated?
Why is my TBT higher than expected?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have any CPU throttling enabled for your performance trace, otherwise there would be a warning icon next to the Performance tab.

With throttling:

[image]

Without:

[image]

However, by default Lighthouse runs with [CPU throttling](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/docs/throttling.md#cpu-throttling) enabled:

> Lighthouse applies CPU throttling to emulate a mid-tier mobile device even when run on far more powerful desktop hardware.

> By default, Lighthouse uses a constant 4x CPU multiplier which moves a typical run in the high-end desktop bracket somewhere into the mid-tier mobile bracket.

As the amount (or lack) of CPU throttling can have a dramatic impact on performance, especially TBT, you should set your manual performance traces to use a 4x CPU slowdown for consistency.

[image]

You can also confirm the exact CPU throttling settings for a given Lighthouse test by hovering over the config at the bottom of the report.